# Acer Aspire V Nitro lagging while running on battery

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, battery, acer

I am completely new to Ubuntu and could not find my problem stated anywhere so far. I would really appreciate some help. :)

I am running an Aspire V Nitro (Intel® Core™ i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz × 8;
GeForce GTX 860M/PCIe/SSE2) with Ubuntu 15.10. Everthing is perfectly fine as long as I have the laptop connected to power. Even if I disconnect the laptop from the powersource and it runs on battery everthing works.

But if i start my laptop only running on battery it is nearly impossible to do anything with it. It lags with every task (open chrome/ firefox) or just using the mouse.

I thought that it may have to do something with the clockspeed of the graphics? Otherwise I have no clue how to fix it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to set you energysettings, which you can find in your systemsettings.

Set everything to `no special settings`

It may be called slightly different as I'm using a Dutch Distro.